# session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm getting this error sometimes from app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php . I'don't know when it's happening just pops up sometimes.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8549819/2047249

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions of that folder where PHP and your Magento stores session files if you have access to this server. The user that PHP is running as must be able to read and write to that folder.

Also check if there are any other scripts that delete session files. For example there is a separate cron job in Debian that cleans up old session files. Now - if something's wrong with the clock or timezones that "being an old file" may occur in wrong time. However, the latter is just my guess.

Comment: It's a Windows Server 2008, and this happens just sometimes (not often). And there's a problem with timezones. So your second answer seems right for me. I'll test that but till' that, thank you!